# .Net core read xls files

Tags: excel, console-application, .net-core, xls, epplus

I am trying to read **.XLS** file in my **.NetCore** console application which will hosted in Azure environment. I am using **EPPlus.Core** (version 1.3.2) and getting the below error

"**EPPlus can not open the package. Package is an OLE compound document. If this is an encrypted package, please supply the password**"

I think XLS file is not supported by EPPlus core

Please suggest me a solution  to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 7):

.xls isn't supported by EPPlus at all - it only deals with .xlsx and they have no plans to support the older file format.

I use the ExcelDataReader package on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExcelDataReader/) / [GitHub](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) with .Net 4.5 - they've been talking about releasing a .Net Core version for a while now, so you may have some luck there.

**Clarification:**
I use EPPlus for everything related to .xlsx files - I use ExcelDataReader solely for reading .xls files.

Comment: According to the GitHub page, ExcelDataReader can indeed be used to read excel spreadsheets in .Net Core